Deploy to Maven Central: gpg: skipped "6919F5E8": No secret key gpg: signing failed: No secret key
Seven years ago or so, I created a Java library and put it on Maven Central. Here is the library on Maven Central
I needed to solve a bug and have now problems getting the new version on Maven Central. The command
mvn deploy

fails because of the gpg plugin.
Here is my pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.github.florianingerl.util</groupId>
    <artifactId>regex</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.11</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <name>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}</name>
    <description>This is a Regular Expressions library for Java. Compared to java.util.regex, it supports Recursive and Conditional Regular Expressions, Capture Trees and Plugins.</description>
    <url>https://github.com/florianingerl/com.florianingerl.util.regex</url>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>GNU General Public License, version 2</name>
            <url>https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.en.html</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/florianingerl/com.florianingerl.util.regex.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://github.com/florianingerl/com.florianingerl.util.regex.git</developerConnection>
        <url>http://github.com/florianingerl/com.florianingerl.util.regex/tree/master</url>
    </scm>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>Florian Ingerl</name>
            <email>imelflorianingerl@gmail.com</email>
            <organization>Florian Ingerl</organization>
            <organizationUrl>https://github.com/florianingerl</organizationUrl>
        </developer>
    </developers>

<!--
    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement> -->

    <distributionManagement>
  <snapshotRepository>
    <id>ossrh</id>
    <url>https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
   <repository>
    <id>ossrh</id>
    <url>https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
  </repository>
</distributionManagement>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <gpg.keyname>6919F5E8</gpg.keyname>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.9</source>
                    <target>1.9</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sign</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <!--
                        <configuration>
                            <keyname>${gpg.keyname}</keyname>
                            <passphraseServerId>${gpg.keyname}</passphraseServerId>
                        </configuration> -->
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

<!--
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.7</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
                    <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                    <autoReleaseAfterClose>false</autoReleaseAfterClose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin> -->

            <plugin>
      <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.7</version>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
      <configuration>
        <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
        <nexusUrl>https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
        <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>

The error message on mvn deploy is:
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\imelf\git\com.florianingerl.util.regex\regex\target\regex-1.1.11-javadoc.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gpg:1.5:sign (sign-artifacts) @ regex ---
gpg: skipped "6919F5E8": No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  31.469 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-06-02T13:59:18+02:00

I have gpg installed which I can verify by typing
gpg --version

into my terminal, which gives the output
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.40
libgcrypt 1.10.1-unknown
Copyright (C) 2022 g10 Code GmbH
License GNU GPL-3.0-or-later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: /home/imelf/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2

I have also read the documentation from Sonatype. The command
gpg --list-signatures

gives me no output at all, nor does
gpg --list-keys

Seven years ago, I have however saved two files private.key and public.key, which I don't know how to use and how to attach to this question.
My GPG installation seems to be in two folders. The name of the first one is Gpg4win. Inside is bin\kleopatra.exe which shows me that I have a certificate. Name: Florian Ingerl (Hobby Java Developer ) Email: ... Gültig bis: 15.2.2029 Schlüssel-Kennung.
The other folder is GnuPG where there is \bin\gpg.exe
It seems (from the output of gpg --list-keys) that I have now no keys although I had one 7 years ago (of course I have deinstalled gpg since then and bought a new computer ).
Do I simply have to create a new key here withgpg --gen-key
So it doesn't matter which key I used for gpg to upload seven years ago?

In my opinion, it does not matter if you generate a new PGP/GPG pair. The only thing that matters is that the files are signed. Only your username and password give you access to Sonatype and that you can upload the library under your GroupID. Sonatype has to allow different signed libraries because several developer from local environment can upload libraries under the same GroupID and ArtifactID.

@Bademeister Thanks a lot! The generation of a new key worked brilliantly and mvn deploy went now through without any errors! It says Remote staging repositories released! I guess that I will be able to see my new version on Maven Central the next days? Or do I have do do something else?

It usually takes up to 30 minutes for the package to be distributed to all systems. One time it has taken one days. See Availability of publishing systems (3/4 April / https://status.maven.org/). I have tried to publish on these two days. A release on the SNAPSHOT environment is usually available immediately. Please note, however, that Sonatype is currently restructuring the systems behind Maven Central. You may soon need to publish a token instead of a user name and password. You should have received information to your registered email at Sonatype.

It took two days, but now my new version 1.1.11 is on Maven Central. I have used the token instead of the username and password already (because I read the documentation :) ) I didn't receive any mail. Here is the library https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.florianingerl.util/regex
